# p7s file and javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I use this code to read an email String in S/Mime format in a certificated email. This is a snippet

```
InputStream inputStreamObj = new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes());
MimeMessage mimeMessageObj = new MimeMessage(session, inputStreamObj);
Object content = mimeMessageObj.getContent();
if (content instanceof Multipart) {
   Multipart multiPart = (Multipart)content;
   for (int i = 0; i < multiPart.getCount(); i++) {
      BodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(i);
      if (part.getFileName() != null) {
          System.out.println("Filename:"+part.getFileName());
      } else if (part.getContent() instanceof Multipart) {
          System.out.println("Multipart");
          //here there is a recursive call to this method
      } else if (part.getContent() instanceof String) {
          System.out.println("Message text: "+part.getContent());
      } else {
          System.out.println("NOT RECOGNIZED TYPE");
      }
    }
}
```

In this manner I see:

```
Message text: <message in html form>
Message text: <message in txt form>
File: daticert.xml
File: postacert.eml
```

**But here "smime.p7s" file is missing**

How can I find this? In the String message (message) I see it:

```
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"
```

Where is the file???

Maybe I cannot use MimeMessage and I must use javax.mail.Message? And how can I convert the text in Message?

Comment: One second, I wasn't clear. Do you want to print content of p7s or you want a "p7s file"?

Comment: I have a text representation of the email (it is correct formatted) and load it in a MimeMessage object. From this moment I need to extract all the attached files, even .p7s file

Comment: Hmm, I have managed to pull bytes from inputStream with getting bodyPart header getHeader("Content-Disposition")[0]. Now lets see what can we do with it.

Comment: There's undoubtedly something wrong in the code you're not showing us.  See the [msgshow.java sample program](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/msgshow.java) for how to process all parts of a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
The message-text received contains all (headers + bodypart). When managed, it "loose" headers parts. Adding these in the first message-text I now see all the attachments, even p7s file.
This file, infact, is nested to the main email using a code binding (printing the txt you can see it), but this link suffer of missing headers. In this manner, without headers, noone can address the p7s file.

The solution is: add headers in the form "name: value\n" at the beginning of the txt-message.